# Are these exports identical in function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

Are these exports identical? For me, one works and the other doesn't but I don't know the difference.

**Working**

```
const faqStore = new Vapi({
    baseURL: 'http://domain.test/api',
    state: {
        faqs: [],
    }
}).get({
    action: 'getFaqs',
    property: 'faqs',
    path: '/faqs'
})

export default faqStore.getStore()
```

**Not Working**

```
export default () => {
    const faqStore = new Vapi({
        baseURL: 'http://domain.test/api',
        state: {
            faqs: [],
        }
    }).get({
        action: 'getFaqs',
        property: 'faqs',
        path: '/faqs'
    })

    return faqStore.getStore()
}
```

How can I get the none working example to behave like the working example so I can pass an argument to the function?

And this is how they are being used respectively...

**Working**

```
import faqStore from './faqs'
...
await store.registerModule('faqs', faqStore));
```

**Not working**

```
import faqStore from './faqs'
...
await store.registerModule('faqs', faqStore());
```

Comment: No, they are not equivalent. The first exports the return value of `faqStore.getStore()`. The second one exports a function (that calls `faqStore.getStore()`). But they are both valid. Whether they "work" or not depends on how they are used.

Comment: Your first example seems odd because, as @FelixKling said, it export the *return value* of `getStore()`, and since you're using this as a module, that value will never change once it's computed (i.e. any other module that imports this one will always get that same value, no way to update it). I suspect that might not be what you intend.

Comment: question updated to show how it's being used @FelixKling

Comment: In what way is it not working? Does it throw an error?

Comment: Am I missing something or are the Working and Not working code the same?

Comment: @Barmar the only difference is they way they are exported and being called. I get no errors but my application doesn't work as expected with the second examples.

Comment: *"doesn't work as expected"* If you don't tell us what you expect, then we cannot explain why that might be. If the `await store.registerModule('faqs', ...));` is executed more then once, then the obvious difference is in the first case, you are always using the same store (instance) whereas in the second case you always get a different store instance.

Answer (score 1):

You're exporting a function instead a value. This turns your *not working* into *working* by evaluating the function before exporting it, just like you do in your working code:

```
export default (() => {
    const faqStore = new Vapi({
        baseURL: 'http://domain.test/api',
        state: {
            faqs: [],
        }
    }).get({
        action: 'getFaqs',
        property: 'faqs',
        path: '/faqs'
    })

    return faqStore.getStore()
})()
```